# Two columns in a table

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-tables

I'm trying to figure out how it is possible to construct a table with two columns (left and right) so that when left column' content ends the right column takes over it (see example).
I'm sure there's a way to do it without floats but correct me if I'm wrong.

[image: Layout]

Comment: This is a table column? are you using this table for tabular data or layout?

Comment: That's the whole purpose of a float.

Comment: `colspan="2"` for the cells that "take over"... **Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/sGLDG/

Comment: Is there a way to do this without knowing when Column 1 ends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `colspan` like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>a1</td>
        <td>b1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a2</td>
        <td>b2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">ab3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">ab4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```